# Semantic UI React change default font

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Tried to follow few sites (e.g. [this link](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html)) where it's shown how to do the customization in default theme but I am not quite following.

I have managed to pulled the "semantic ui" package and find src/site/globals/site.variables which I should modify.

Let's say I want to use the Time news roman font style in all Semantic components. Then I want to build it to get the final css file.
How can I achieve that?

I am not very experienced in frontend stuff so please be patient with me.

Comment: You should use gulp to convert semantic less files into css and then include it on your application. This way you will be able to see the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.variables` and `.overrides` files are used by the Semantic UI build scripts. All available `gulp` scripts are located here: https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html#gulp-commands

To run those builds, you would `cd` into the folder that you installed Semantic UI in and then run one of those commands. The simplest would be to run `gulp build` for a one time build. For continuous builds each time a file changes, you would want to run `gulp watch`.